How to use string slices in Rust targeting WebAssembly
I've developped a library in Rust to parse RTF content. I've initially targeted x86 architectures. So I have use lots of string slices (&str) to reference to the original source without copying its content. For instance, a Token looks like :
enum Token<'a> {
    PlainText(&'a str),
    OpeningBracket,
    ClosingBracket,
    ...
}

I want to update my library to also target WebAssembly. I have taken a look into the wasm-bingen  crate, an the Rust Wasm book, and it looks like wasm_bindgen doesn't support references nor lifetimes.
Is there an elegant solution for me to adapt my codebase to support WebAssembly without sacrificing the initial performances ?
I have conditional compilation, but I still have the lifetime issue :
#[cfg(not(target_arch = "wasm32"))]
pub type StrRef<'a> = &'a str;
#[cfg(target_arch = "wasm32")]
pub type StrRef = String;

How can I expose this Token enum, for instance, to be used in a JS environement ?

What do you mean WebAssembly does'nt support references nor lifetimes ? of course it does. What are you trying to take a reference to ?

The wasm-bindgen crate doesn't support them. I'm trying to reference string slices, and have a consistent codebase between x86 and wasm.

I probably have an answer for you, but I need some clarification. Can you please [edit] your question to include the following: (1) Is your goal to write a Rust library that can be compiled in the wasm32 target, to write a Rust library that can be used directly from JavaScript, or something else? (2) What exact problem did you experience when trying to use your code with references, unmodified? wasm-bindgen only cares about #[wasm_bindgen] annotated items, so merely compiling for wasm should work if you don't make other changes.

Thanks for your answer, I have edited my question. I want to expose the Token enum to JS, but I had trouble doing it with wasm-bindgen due to the &str reference and the lifetime which both are not supported for now.

There are more problems here than you've found.

JavaScript does not have a borrow checker, so there’s no zero-cost way to use long-lived references across the FFI boundary, because nothing can ensure they remain valid when used. You cannot return a type with a lifetime to JS, at all.

You can’t share strings without copying, either. JavaScript Strings are opaque — you cannot access their bytes, only their characters — but likely to be encoded in UTF-16. A Rust &str by definition points to text encoded in UTF-8. So, there is not and cannot be a way to freely share string buffers between JavaScript and Rust.
(You can avoid copying the text of a string by using a js_sys::JsString which points to the JS String object in the JS heap, but then you have to do individual bridged operations to access text from that string, so it's unlikely to be faster.)

Your Token type won't work at all. You can't export an enum with fields, because JS doesn't have enums / discriminated union types. You’ll need to find a way to express your tokens as JS objects.


Given all of these issues, I would recommend that instead of trying to use conditional compilation to adjust type definitions, you create separate types and functions dedicated to providing the JS-compatible API that makes the most sense for JS. Approach this as wrapping your existing library, not as modifying it to be compatible.
In fact, you should consider making this JS binding wrapper a separate crate that depends on your library. If you insert #[wasm_bindgen] exports in your main Rust library, this means that every Rust-to-WebAssembly build including your library will include all those exports to JS, even if your library is being used solely by other Rust code within that one Wasm module. (This could even cause a name conflict.) Keeping it separate means that the JS exports are only present when they are needed.

Thanks you for your answer, I thinks that I will adopt the separate crate solution which seems the best for my case.
